# Transaction scope always escalates to MSDTC and erros when calling save changes on and entity context. Even with only one entity context

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

My entity context has a connection to SQLServer 2008 R2.

Below is the code i am calling, it is very simple and I have put it in a transaction to demonstrate the issue (event though the transaction has no purpose for this example)

I receive a "MSDTC on server unavailable" error when the save changes is called. However i thought it would not escalate to MSDTC if only one context is being used. Am i missing something here?

```
       MyEntities entity = new MyEntities();
    using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {


        entityy.Groups.AddObject(new Group
    {
        InstanceId = 1000
        ,
        Name = "TransactionGroup",
        InsertedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        InsertedBy = LoggedInUser,
        LastUpdatedBy = LoggedInUser
    });


       entity.SaveChanges();


    ts.Complete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the context (MyEntities entity) inside the transactionscope using declaration.

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
   using(MyEntities entity = new MyEntities())
   {
     //... your code ...
     //...
     entity.SaveChanges();
   }
   ts.Complete();
}
```